# How to encode RTMP URL to stream?

Tags: streaming, urlencode, red5, rtmp

Like youtube I want to stream my videos using some code instead of actual video name.
I am using red5 server. And, oflaDemo is working fine for video streaming. But all I want to change the rtmp url.

For now, its something like this

```
rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/myvideo.mp4
```

Now, I want something like this,

```
rtmp://localhost/xxx4555xzeefdakdaf
```

What should I change to get this. Where the mapping is done in red5?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a "handler" for all incoming requests and parse / decode the url. If you don't create your own class here, that specified url would look only for an "application" named "xxx4555xzeefdakdaf". Off the top of my head, I'd say you should look at extending "ScopeResolver" and working from there; you'll find its bean entry in the red5/webapps/red5-default.xml file.

Comment: Thank you Mondain for your reply.
I got source code from here    

https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

But, I am not getting how to compile it. Any suggestions will be helpful.